# Numbered occurrences for preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, regex, callback

I'm trying to figure out how to identify the order of occurrences for matched regex groups. but can't find any such functionality. Yet, I'm sure it has to be there and I'm just doing something wrong...

So far I have this:

```
$string = "SELECT id, title FROM table WHERE id = ?d AND qwe=?s";
$pattern = '/(\?+[sdf]{1})/i';
$data = array(111, 222, 333);
$inc = 0;

function callback($matches) {
    global $inc, $data;
    $inc++;

    switch ($matches[0]) {
        case '?s':
            return '`'.$data[$inc].'`';
        case '?d':
            return (int) $data[$inc];
        case '?f':
            return (double) $data[$inc];
    }
}
print_r(preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'callback', $string));
```

It works, but that thing with $inc is certainly not the way to go...

I want to avoid using $inc at all here. Is there a way to know the order of occurrences when these regex groups are matched? That's what I'm trying to do. So, maybe I will have not only the matches, but a number that will tell me what match this is in order.

Is there a better solution to this problem?

Comment: Is your code is working fine? I got an error in your code.

Comment: Yes, it's working. I forgot one thing when copying the code here. I fixed it now. Can you try again?

Comment: If my answer proved helpful, please also consider upvoting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mix up two things: multiple matches and groups. When you have groups, you can access them (by name or by ID). When you have multiple matches (and when you use `preg_replace...`, you actually have the regex engine find all non-overlapping matches in the text and process them *individually*), the regex engine does not know if it is the first, or second, etc. So, there is no other way *with the current input data* than using a counter.

*If you can change the input data*, I suggest using a key-value `$data` array where keys will be equal to the variables you want to match in the text (`s`, `f`, or `d`). In order to access them from inside a match, you need to *capture* `[sfd]` in your regex, i.e. you need to wrap that character class with a capturing group.

Use

```
$string = "SELECT id, title FROM table WHERE id = ?d AND qwe=?s";
$pattern = '/\?+([sdf])/i';
$data = array("s" => 111, "d" => 222, "f" => 333);
$inc = 0;

echo preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($matches) use ($data) {
    switch ($matches[0]) {
        case '?s':
            return '`'.$data[$matches[1]].'`';
        case '?d':
            return (int) $data[$matches[1]];
        case '?f':
            return (double) $data[$matches[1]];
    }
}, $string);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/IAA8M3).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [closure](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) instead of a global:

```
$data = array(111, 222, 333);
$inc = 0;
$callback = function ($matches) use (&$data, &$inc) {
  // ...
};
print_r($preg_replace_callback($pattern, $callback, $string);
```

This will not expose `$inc` and `$data` to a wider scope like `global` would.

Comment: I want to avoid using $inc at all here. Is there a way to know the order of occurrences when these regex groups are matched? That's what I'm trying to do. So, maybe I will have not only the matches, but a number that will tell me what match this in order.

Comment: Ah, that. I misunderstood, I thought "that thing with $inc" was the `global` bit that was the problem.

Comment: Ah, sorry for misunderstanding. I will update my question.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, the `$inc` bit is necessary. `preg_replace_callback` does have the fifth parameter "count: If specified, this variable will be filled with the number of replacements done.", but only seems to be set at the end, after all replacements are done. Still, using closures is better than using globals.

Comment: Hm... When groups are matched they can be referenced in the regex itself as '$1', etc. Is there really no way to expose that...

Answer (score 0):

The method which you are using is perfectly okay, but if you want to change you can use this one.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/782225)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string = "SELECT id, title FROM table WHERE id = ?d AND qwe=?s";
$data = array(111, 222, 333);
$pattern = '/(?:\?+[sdf])/i';
$counter=0;

while(preg_match($pattern, $string,$matches,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE))
{
    switch ($matches[0][0]) 
    {
        case '?s':
            $replacement= '`'.$data[$counter].'`';
            break;
        case '?d':
            $replacement= (int) $data[$counter];
            break;
        case '?f':
            $replacement= (double) $data[$counter];
            break;
    }
    $string=substr_replace($string,$replacement,$matches[0][1], strlen($matches[0][0]));
    $counter++;
}
echo $string;
```